# Gunicorn is not seeing new settings

Tags: django, gunicorn

I updated one environment variable inside `settings.py` and restarted `gunicorn`, but it is seeing the old settings. Here is the command I use to start it:

`nohup /opt/my_proj/.virtualenvs/my_proj/bin/python2 /opt/my_proj/.virtualenvs/my_proj/bin/gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8008 --timeout=1800 --log-level=debug --error-logfile=/opt/my_proj/gunicorn_nik.log --enable-stdio-inheritance --capture-output --user=me --pythonpath=/opt/me/code/my_proj,/opt/me/code/my_proj/seqr_settings wsgi &`

I printed out paths to make sure that the scripts are running under my 'my_proj' directory and also looked up in 'gunicorn_nik.log' verifying that there I see it pointing to 'my_proj' folder. Then I removed `settings.py` to make sure still that it is the file `gunicorn` is picking up. The startup failed. I tried modifying `settings.py` printing out something from it but it is not working, `logger.info` is not printing from there.

I have several `Django` projects on one cluster node running (not sure that it is important).

Its as if `Django` is storing some cached file and using it, but how come `gunicorn` restart does not fix it? Seems weird to me. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in `.bashrc` an environment variable was set that was somehow overwriting the value in `settings.py` that was having the same name.